# Scroll a Large Picture in a small block

Tags: jquery-plugins

I want to scroll a large picture in a small block.  But when I put the large image in a small block, the layout is broken; the image just extends out of the block. I found a nice library which could resolve this. Check this out:

http://www.viget.com/inspire/jquery-image-scroller-plugin/

http://www.viget.com/uploads/file/image-scroller/

Answer (score 0):

Did use the style `overflow: hidden;` on the container? Also, I already used image-scroller from viget, works well :)